# How to run gnuplot by just typing 'gp' in osx?

Tags: osx, gnuplot

When I use cent os or ubuntu, I just type 'gp' to run gnuplot.

Of course, typing 'gnuplot' also works.

But it doesn't work in osx terminal.

How to make 'gp' possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type this line at your terminal and you should be able to call gnuplot by executing gp

```
alias gp='gnuplot'
```

If you want to make it permanent, add this line to the startup script of your shell. It's `~/.bashrc` if you use bash, or `~/.zshrc` if you use zsh.